# Link to a line in a HTML?

Tags: html, text, hyperlink

Is it possible to link to a line number in a html file? I want to link someone to part of a very large document which is on a webpage but the whole thing is in one tag so is not split into sections with IDs I can link to.

[Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/934972-spelling-jungle/faqs/44591) is the page I'm talking to, id like to link to "LEVEL 46" can I do this?

I would be just as happy with another workaround such as searching for the text or anything, I assume this could be made more complicated by it being in various wrappers, assuming it was just a plain .txt file could you do it?

Edit: **im not writing the web page im trying to link to a part of someone elses, so i cannot add IDs etc**

Comment: Have you looked at using anchors with "#" values?

Comment: im not writing the page, im trying to link to someone elses

Comment: while somewhat off topic, beaker is pretty awesome

Comment: @Alohci if you can perhaps find a way of backing that up ill accept it as an answer

Comment: Without any IDs, No YOU CANT. Easy way to find a text: **Ctrl + F**  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#a-place-in-the-document></a>

...


<h1 id="a-place-in-the-document">There's a link to here!</h1>
```

The link will have the page jump to the element with the specified ID.

For example: `http://example.com#hello` will link to `http://example.com` and immediately go to the element with ID of `hello`.

---

In the case where you can't have IDs (such as in text files on gamefaqs), you'd need to provide a search string, for people to quickly search and find whatever section you need (such as `[LV46]`), and have your readers to search for it.

Comment: my question is if there is no IDs to link to

Comment: @Jacxel: Oh, than you can't :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert all of your Headings into anchor tags.

So for your example the link would be:

```
   <a href="#Level46">
```

The heading itself would be:

```
   <h1 id="Level46">Level 46</h1>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now that you have amended your question, this answer isnt really relevant. You can link to other parts of their page, if they have id's that you can reference, but since that page isnt set up like that, I dont think its possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a text file, or a collection of text files in a directory structure, you can create a parallel directory structure so people can browse

```
http://pdssbn.astro.umd.edu/holdings/
```

as

```
http://pdssbn.astro.umd.edu/byline/holdings/
```

and generate line numbers and/or anchors to individual lines on the fly, even if other non-text files are under the /holdings/ tree, with an Apache HTTPd **AliasMatch** like this

```
AliasMatch /byline/holdings/.*[.](asc|cat|lbl|tab|txt) /path/cgi-bin/pds_byline.cgi
```

and a symlink e.g. assuming your tree is under top/ e.g. top/holdings/,

```
ln -s . .../top/byline
```

and a simple script (cgi-bin/pds_byline.cgi above) that converts the text file to HTML on the fly.  I have created a Git repo to do just that [here](https://github.com/drbitboy/www_byline); that is configured for Planetary Data System (PDS) data sets under http://pdssbn.astro.umd.edu/holdings/.

You would of course need access to the Apache HTTPd configuration files (/etc/httpd/conf/conf/*/*.conf) to do this, to put in a

```
<Directory .../top/cgi-bin>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

entry to use a .htaccess file in cgi-bin/, and the **AliasMatch** above, at a minimum.  N.B. AliasMatch cannot go into the .htaccess file.

Caveat:  this only creates anchors by line number; if the file changes over time then existing links to those line numbers will be broken; you could of course do the same thing instead looking for specific text strings like "Level 46" and inserting the relevant anchors on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

`<a name="destination" id="destination"></a>Destination anchors`

```
<a href="#destination">Destination anchors </a>
```

Source:
http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/anchor.php#destination

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could define an anchor for the specific line as, for example, a section element. Then you could link to that anchor.

```
<section name"sec1">
<a href="sec1">
```